# How to enforce that only 1 instance of service interface can exists, with exception of Default in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have a interface `IStorageService`. User can use application configuration to configure different services. All services will be created as with `@Bean @ConditionalOnExpression(...)`. How can i enforce that only one Storage service can exist? I know that you need to explisitly configure to allow beanoverrides, but i need to have a DefaultStorageService if none are configured and if configuration exists, then only one service should be created that will override the DefaultService. If more than one is configured to be created i want the startup to throw an error and fail. How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to implement `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` if you want to check the bean definitions or `BeanPostProcessor` if you want to check bean instances.
for the first case you need to implements `postProcessBeanFactory` method in which you have a total control on BeanFactory
for example you could check the list of registered beans of type `IStorageService`  using `getBeanNamesForType(IStorageService.class)` method and register the default `IStorageService` using `registerSingleton` if no bean is configured

Comment: Seems like BeanFactoryPostPRocessor is what i need. Will get back once i have run some tests with it.